# Smallest eigenvalue of a type of irreducible matrices with diagonal perturbation

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an irreducible matrix such that $a_{ii}=\sum\limits_{j=1,j\ne i}^n |a_{ij}|$ for all $i=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $a_{ij} \in \{0,-1\}$ for all $i\ne j$. Note that the eigenvalue of $A$ is non-negative.

Then, denote a diagonal matrix with only one non-zero diagonal entry as $$\Delta=diag\{0,\ldots,0,\varepsilon,0,\ldots,0\}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$ where $\varepsilon < 0.$

Then, can we prove that the smallest eigenvalue of $A+\Delta$ is negative?

Comment: Your first line equality about $a_{i,i}$ is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the equality has been revised.

Comment: Your new equality implies that $a_{i,j}=0$ when $i\not= j$.

Comment: Just revised, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT. The answer is YES.

Since $A$ is irreducible, each $a_{i,i}$ is $>0$ and $u=\max (a_{i,i})>0$. Note that if $\lambda\in spectrum(A)$, then $\lambda$ is in the closed disc $D(u,u)$. In particular, if $\lambda\not= 0$ then $0< Re(\lambda)\leq 2u$.

Let $\epsilon >0$, $\Delta=\epsilon E_{i,i}$. Then $B=-A+uI$ is irreducible non-negative and $\rho(B)=u$, a bound reached by the eigenvalue $u$ (indeed, the eigenvalues of $B$ are in $D(0,u)$). Moreover, $u$ is a simple eigenvalue (Perron-Frobenius).

$B+\Delta=-(A-\Delta)+uI\geq B$ implies that $\rho(B+\Delta)\geq \rho(B)$. Assume that $\rho(B+\Delta)=\rho(B)$; according to Wielandt, for every $j$, $(B+\Delta)_{j,j}$ and $B_{j,j}$ must have same modulus, that is false for $(i,i)$; then $\rho(B+\Delta)>\rho(B)=u$ and $\rho(B+\Delta)$ is reached by a $>0$ eigenvalue $u+\tau$. Finally $A-\Delta$ admits $-\tau<0$ as eigenvalue and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the example but the matrix $A$ is not an irreducible matrix.

Comment: @user96212  . I see that you say "thanks" when the solution does not suit you;  however, when it suits you, you do not even have the courtesy to say "thank you my dog".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the proof in the answer is interesting and helpful, thanks!